# Alignment of tspans inside text

Tags: svg, position, tspan

I seem to not be able to solve this issue despite reading similar issues on SO. I would like my legend and sublegend (so the two tspans inside the text) to align on the x-attribute (So Austin and Detail sublegend should start at the same x position:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/fef1xqdt/5/

```
<svg width=500 height=500>
<g  class="legend" transform="translate(50,30)" data-style-padding="10" style="font-size: 20px;"> 
<rect class="legend-box" x="-18" y="-28" height="152" width="175.828125"></rect>
<g>
<text y="0em" x="1em" >
<tspan dx="0" text-anchor="start">Austin</tspan><tspan dx="0" dy="20" text-anchor="start" style="font-size: 16px;">Detail Sublegend</tspan></text>
<text y="2em" x="1em">New York</text>
<text y="4em" x="1em">San Francisco</text>
<circle cy="-0.25em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);"></circle>
<circle cy="1.75em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle>
<circle cy="3.75em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></circle></g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I read that whitespace between tspans messes things up...I don't have any. I would really like to understand why putting dx="0" for both tspans doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set them to have the same x position if that's what you want. The different font size means it doesn't look quite right though. Maybe you could add some additional delta bodge factor to cope with that.

```css
.legend rect {
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
  opacity:0.8;}
```

```html
<svg width=500 height=500>
<g  class="legend" transform="translate(50,30)" data-style-padding="10" style="font-size: 20px;"> 
<rect class="legend-box" x="-18" y="-28" height="152" width="175.828125"></rect>
<g>
<text y="0em" x="1em" >
  <tspan dx="0" text-anchor="start">Austin</tspan><tspan x="1em" dy="20" text-anchor="start" style="font-size: 16px;">Detail Sublegend</tspan></text>
<text y="2em" x="1em">New York</text>
<text y="4em" x="1em">San Francisco</text>
<circle cy="-0.25em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);"></circle>
<circle cy="1.75em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle>
<circle cy="3.75em" cx="0" r="0.4em" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></circle></g>
</g>
</svg>
```